# Seeing bit count of RSA in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security

When I surf on an HTTPS site in Chrome, how can I see the bit count used by their RSA encryption? (e.g. 1024 bit, 2048 bit...)

Comment: Maybe you'll find this question helpful: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/5607

Comment: Note that this is the bit count used for the signature verification that makes sure you reached the site you intended to reach. It has nothing to do with the encryption used to protect the data exchanged against interception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least following procedure shows the bit count:

```
Click on the lock icon on address bar.
Select 'Connection' tab.
Click 'Certificate Information'.
Select 'Details' tab.
Depending on Chrome version, it's already visible or can be found from 'Certificate fields'.
```